# Install manually custom keyboard layout (dll) created with MSKLC

Tags: windows, windows-registry, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

I created a custom keyboard layout with the [Microsoft Keyboard Layouter Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134) (MSKLC) tool and generated a "build package" which allows an easy installation. The installation of the keyboard layout requires administratior priviliges. It copies basically the generated `.DLL` file (which is part of the build result) to `C:\windows\system32` and register it in the Windows Registry.

In my case I want to use the same keyboard layout on a system where I have limited priviliges. However I'm able to modify the Windows Registry.

So I tried the following (on a pc where I have administrator priviliges):

1. Copy `custom.dll` to `C:\custom.dll`
2. Change the path from an existing (already registered) keyboard layout to `..\..\custom.dll`; for example: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\0000100c`; `Layout File = ..\..\custom.dll`
3. Select the keyboard layout in the system settings for which the file path to his related DLL was modified (in this case the "Swiss French" layout).

<strike>It works!</strike> It didn't work. (at first I had the impression that it worked, but I must have mixed something up.). It seems the files must be located within `C:\windows\system32` and can't be referenced with a relative path.

Basically I want to use the custom keyboard layout (DLL) but I cant use the generated deployment package since I have no priviliges to write files to `C:\windows\system32`. But I could modify the Windows Registry. Is there a way for me to still load this layout?

My OS: Windows 10 x64

Comment: I'm not sure to comprehend. If you could successfully copy it and install it in C:\custom\custom.dll - why not use this path? You wish to distribute this package, like to the public? That's a risky thing (you can brick systems) and I guess drivers/keyboard packages have strict guidelines for installation, including signature, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft already released an update for older Windows versions in 2012 that verifies that the keyboard layouts are contained in `%Windir%\System32` and are not located somewhere else and referenced by relative paths.

See "[MS12-034: Description of the security update for CVE-2012-0181 in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003: May 8, 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/ms12-034-description-of-the-security-update-for-cve-2012-0181-in-windows-xp-and-windows-server-2003-may-8-2012-e4e0f3ec-1eb4-2d96-c0ea-5f9b658a62df)"

> **How does this update work?**
>
> This update enumerates all the keyboard layout files that are registered on your computer, and then it verifies that they are all in the %Windir%\System32 folder.

Microsoft wants to make sure the keyboard layout files are in the right directory. If it's otherwise possible, it would be security bug. I can't find anything specific about this for Windows 10, but it can be assumed that the same logic applies here.

To answer my original question: It is not possible to register the keyboard layout without being able to copy the DLL file to `%Windir%\System32`.